# Skills required for outlook add-in development

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, outlook-addin

I am complete new for the  outlook add-in development, Just confused from where to start As per I see on internet it is based on java script library called office.js , As I am a web developer developing in xpages.

I have a good knowledge of javascript as well as jquery. Is some thing specific needed for this like .Net or C# to develop Outlook addins.

I am bit confused also for hiring any one with, `what knowlege?` to develop addins. I see lot of experts on stack overflow but cannot contact any one directly to ask about getting hired.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/